# PHP query get result from select

Tags: php, mysql

hi I need help with 2 mysql queries I am working on. I need to get data from first query and use it in second query.

**First query** (get different extension for domains)

```
$resultExt = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM extension”) or die(mysql_error());    
while($rowExt = mysql_fetch_array( $resultExt )) {
$extDom = $rowExt[‘ext’];     
$postDom = 'Domain_’ . $extDom ;      
$dom_to_show .= '$rowCart[$postDom];';        
}
```

and I get my list of domain extensions

```
$Domain_com = $rowCart[‘Domain_com’]; $Domain_net  = $rowCart[‘Domain_net’];
```

and so on

**Second Query** (get data from cart)
then I need to get data from cart table

```
$showCart = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cartlist where Session = '".$session."' ORDER BY ID DESC") or die(mysql_error()); 
while($rowCart = mysql_fetch_array( $showCart )) {

//here i need to get variable like $Domain_com = $rowCart['Domain_com’];

//if I use echo   $dom_to_show; or   $dom_to_show; I get no result
}
```

what do I need to put inside the second while to get results from query?

thanks

Comment: well I can see an error in your first query, you are using both `"` and `”`

Comment: I think there should be an auto check feature in SO where questions that have both `php` and `mysql` tags check for use of deprecated APIs. Otherwise, someone would come and point out anyway.

Comment: You need to make sure that $session is set, as @chriz mentionend, you are using " and other ticks, f.e. it needs to be $rowExt["ext"]. You should stop using mysql_ as it is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

The echo should echo out a result, i have added an array that will get all the data in the row and output it after it has ran. This will help you see if there is any data returned from the query.

```
$showCart = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cartlist where Session = '".$session."' ORDER BY ID DESC") or die(mysql_error()); 
while($rowCart = mysql_fetch_array( $showCart )) {

//here i need to get variable like $Domain_com = $rowCart['Domain_com’];
//if I use echo   $dom_to_show; or   $dom_to_show; I get no result

    echo $rowCart['Domain_com'];
  //or

   $array[] = $rowCart;

}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
```

also

```
$rowCart['Domain_com'];
```

was set to

```
$rowCart['Domain_com’];
```

which is wrong.

Comment: thanks if I use echo $rowCart['Domain_com'];
it works, but I need to use the variable $dom_to_show from previous query